# SELENIUM Unable to close new tab

Tags: java, selenium

i been working on the selenium driver which i have to close the new tab else the current Testcase will fail due unable to allocate the directory of xpath. I notice that im calling 3 times of the webdriver , can anyone guide me through the mistake i made? Kindly advise . Thanks you in advance

SignIn_Action:

```
public class SignIn_ActionBuilder {
    static WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

    public static void Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{

        wd.get(Constant.URL);

        wd.manage().window().maximize();

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Home_Page.Skip_Advertising(wd).click();

        Home_Page.lnk_MyAccount(wd).click();

        LogIn_Page.txtbx_UserName(wd).sendKeys(Constant.Username);

        LogIn_Page.txtbx_Password(wd).sendKeys(Constant.Password);

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        LogIn_Page.btn_LogIn(wd).click();

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);




    } 
}
```

Product Selection :

```
public class ProductSelectionConfirmation_Action {
    static WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();



     public static void ThreeDigit_Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{

            // This is to get the Product name on the Confirmation page with using getText()/click method 
            // Once some text is stored in this variable can be used later in any other class 

            wd.manage().wait(120);
            wd.close();

            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.pick_PickLotteryNum1(wd).click();
            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.pick_PickLotteryNum2(wd).click();
            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.pick_PickLotteryNum3(wd).click();

            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ConfirmNumberToBet(wd).click();

             for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
                ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_IncreaseBet(wd).click();
            } 

            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ProceedBet(wd).click();

            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ConfirmBet(wd).click();
            // This is all about Verification checks, these does not stop your execution but simply report fail at the end
            // This is to check that if the value in the variable pick_PickLotteryNum1 is not null, then do this

         }
}
```

TestCase :

```
public class Sobet_WBG_YiWanCai {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test(description = "WBG亿万彩 - 后三码" , enabled = true)
      public void f() throws Exception {
          try{
              SignIn_ActionBuilder.Execute(driver);
              ProductSelectionConfirmation_Action.ThreeDigit_Execute(driver);
              Home_Page.lnk_LogOut(driver);
              Home_Page.btn_LogOutDialog(driver);
              driver.close();
          }catch (Exception e){

              Log.error(e.getMessage());
              throw (e);
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: you mean `driver.close();` not working? what error you are getting?

Comment: @HelpingHands im not getting any error , it wont close the new tab

Comment: No need to call web driver 3 times..just put  `public static WebDriver driver = null;` in class "Sobet_WBG_YiWanCai"

Comment: ok , first do as above then see if it works or not.

Comment: @HelpingHands im getting error of java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pageObjects.ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.pick_PickLotteryNum1(ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.java:70)

Comment: Yes you should get an null pointer according to your code. See my answer below

Comment: @debugger89 Do I need to add static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); on SignIn_ActionBuilder ?

Comment: No you have to remove `static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` lines from your action classes. And you should use the `driver` parameter which is passed in to each execute method for performing webdriver actions

Comment: @debugger89 after i remove the static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); , i getting null value when retrieve the driver.get(Constant.URL);

Comment: Please read my answer till the bottom. I have posted the corrected test method also

Comment: @debugger89 sorry , my mistake .. thanks its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a series of issues with the code you have posted. 
In each of the Action classes you are creating a new static web driver object.

```
static WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Which means it will open a new Firefox browser when the class is called. 
And also you are passing a webdriver object in to the execute methods from the test case. But the passed webdriver is never used in the execute methods.

```
 public static void ThreeDigit_Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{}
```

You are not using the `driver` object for any action in the method but uses the `wd` object throughout the method.

Corrected code for the first class execute method :

```
 public class SignIn_ActionBuilder {

    public static void Execute(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{

       driver.get(Constant.URL);

       driver.manage().window().maximize();

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       Home_Page.Skip_Advertising(driver).click();

       Home_Page.lnk_MyAccount(driver).click();

       LogIn_Page.txtbx_UserName(driver).sendKeys(Constant.Username);

       LogIn_Page.txtbx_Password(driver).sendKeys(Constant.Password);

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       LogIn_Page.btn_LogIn(driver).click();

       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
}
```

And from the test case you have to create a webdriver object and pass it into the execute methods.

```
public class Sobet_WBG_YiWanCai {
public WebDriver driver;

@Test(description = "WBG亿万彩 - 后三码" , enabled = true)
  public void f() throws Exception {
      try{
          //Create the driver instance here.
          driver = new FirefoxDriver();
          SignIn_ActionBuilder.Execute(driver);
          ProductSelectionConfirmation_Action.ThreeDigit_Execute(driver);
          Home_Page.lnk_LogOut(driver);
          Home_Page.btn_LogOutDialog(driver);
          driver.close();
      }catch (Exception e){

          Log.error(e.getMessage());
          throw (e);
      }

  }
}
```

And you have to remove the `static WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();` line from all your action classes.

Comment: Indeed i remove static WebDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver(); but it failed due getting null value of driver.get(Constant.URL);